# react-router-dom v:6 'No routes matched location "/component"'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am transitioning to using `react-router-dom` v6 (used v5 before) and I am running into an unexpected warning when I try to access a specific component using the URL. Example:

- http://localhost:3000/ -> resolves just fine, loads `<Home>` wrapped by `<Layout>`.
- http://localhost:3000/createuser -> resolves, loads `<CreateUser>` wrapped by `<Layout>` **but** I get a `No routes matched location "/createuser"` warning in the console.

Oh, and when I switch between components using `Link` from `react-router-dom` I don't get the warning.

My app works but I'd like to avoid having any warnings, or at least understand them. Any ideas where am I going wrong?

My code is below:

### App.js

```
// ~ cutting out imports for brevity ~
export default function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Root />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

### Root.js

```
// ~ cutting out imports for brevity ~
export const Root = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const authState = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

    useEffect(() => {        
        dispatch(_verifyAuth())
    }, [dispatch])

    if (authState.authenticating) {
        // Show user an empty page while authenticating
        return <div />
    }
    else if (authState.authenticated) {
        // Display different content to different types of user
        if (authState.userData.admin) {
            return <AdminRouter />
        } else if (authState.userData.user) {
            return <UserRouter />
        } else {
            return <ErrorOccured />
        }
    } else {
        // Unauthenticated user needs to first log in
        return <AuthRouter />
    }
}
```

### AdminRouter

```
// ~ cutting out imports for brevity ~
export const Router = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Layout>            
                <Routes>    
                    <Route index element={<Home />} />                
                    <Route path="/createuser" element={<CreateUser />} />
                </Routes>            
            </Layout>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Other than it being odd to render multiple routers and sets of routes (*as opposed to using layout routes to handle authentication checks and redirects*) it's difficult to say why the warning is occurring *other than* the `"/createuser"` route is conditionally rendered so it ***is*** `No routes matched location "/createuser"` sometimes. Can you provide a *running* codesandbox demo that we could inspect live?

Comment: I think you're right. I believe that what's happening is that initially, before `dispatch(_verifyAuth())` kicks in and `authState.authenticated` is true, the app briefly defaults to the `<AuthRouter />`, where there is indeed no `/createuser`.

I will do some reading on layout routes. Thank you!